# VSCode: Remote - SSH extension - nothing happens when trying to conncet to remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have recently discovered vscode and the remote development extension, and wanting to try it out, but I can't get the damn thing to connect to my development server.

I've installed the both the vscode and vscode insiders packages by downloading the .deb packages manually on my local machine and installed the extension it self by executing this line:

```
ext install ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack
```

Afterwards my pre-configured ssh hosts gets discovered fine and i have key-based auth running and it works fine when connecting to the server from a terminal.

But when I try to connect to the server, by right clicking and selecting one of the two options, only a notification saying "Confirming *hostname* is reachable" pops up for a second or two and then nothing else happens.

There are no information in the "output" view, other than this line:

```
remote-ssh@0.42.2
```

I've checked and confirmed the remote server has the needed prerequisites.

Also i see nothing in the /var/log/audit/audit.log on the remote server when trying to connect, so I dont even think it tries to establish a connection.

What am I missing ?

Local OS: Linux Mint 19 Tara

Remote OS: CentOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - "+" signs makes the extension fail: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/612

I have this line in my local .ssh/config

```
Host *+*
  ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | sed 's/+[^+]*$//;s/\([^+%%]*\)%%\([^+]*\)$/\2 -l \1/;s/:/ -p /') nc -q0 $(echo %h | sed 's/^.*+//;/:/!s/$/ %p/;s/:/ /')
```

Which allows me to connect to host b through host a like so:

ssh hosta+hostb

Removing that fixed the issue, and I connect succesfully to a remote host - it simple seems that that vscode dislikes that line.